# meteor mup setup mongo failed sudo: command not found

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ubuntu, meteor, mup

I try to setup my Meteor environment by using :

```
mup setup
```

But I get this error :

```
Me% mup setup
update 1.0.4 => 1.1.2

Started TaskList: Setup Docker
[93.118.34.197] - setup docker
[93.118.34.197] - setup docker: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Setup Meteor
[93.118.34.197] - Setup Environment

Started TaskList: Setup Mongo
[93.118.34.197] - setup environment
[93.118.34.197] x Setup Environment: FAILED

    -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    bash: line 2: sudo: command not found
    bash: line 3: sudo: command not found
    bash: line 4: sudo: command not found
    bash: line 5: sudo: command not found
    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
```

I try this command by using root and no-root account but the error persists.

I didn't find any document which resolve my issue.

Do you have a solution which solve this problem ?

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve this problem by :

- Updating Ubuntu to version 16
- Updating mup to version 1.1.2

I hope it will help you.